# Reiniciar componente hijo ante un evento

Tags: angular

Tengo este componente que llama a uno hijo:

```
<div fxLayaout= "row">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="50"     fxLayoutGap="5px">
    <h2 class="mat-h2">Historial.</h2>
  </div>
<div fxLayout="row"  fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end center">
  <employee-autocomplete
    [control]="name"
    [validateEmployee]="true"
  ></employee-autocomplete>
  <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Buscar historial de empoleado" (click)="actionSearch()">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
</div>

//Acá
<app-employee-historic-list
  *ngIf="show == true"
  [arrayHistory]="historic"
></app-employee-historic-list>
```

Cuándo ocurre el click en el boton que lleva al método actionSearch() quiero hacer que el componente  se reinicie. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Para qué necesitas que se reinicie? o a qué te refieres por reiniciar?

Answer (score 0):

hola buenas bueno en angular tienes que importar esta librería

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

y en el constructor la mandas a llamar

```
constructor(public router: Router){}
```

después creas una función o en esa misma la que tienes la de la de actionSearch tienes que agregar un this.router.navigateByUrl('aqui va el nombre de tu componente');
entonces quedaria algo asi mira:

```
actionSearch(){ this.router.navigateByUrl('nombre de tu componente que quieres recargar'); }
```

otra opción
es agregar en el html

```
[routerLink]="['/nombre de tu componente']"
```

en donde esta el botón para que te redirigía a donde quieras o recargues componente
espero te sirva la información